# OpenVPN device hostname resolution in Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, dns, openvpn

I am running an OpenVPN server on a Windows 10 machine with following server configurations:

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
****ca/cert/key/dh/tls-auth omitted****
server 10.8.1.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.1.1.1"
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

Say this machine as **PC1** (10.1.1.2) and it is **not** the gateway for my LAN (10.1.1.0/24);
there is a wireless router running as the gateway (10.1.1.1).

Remote client (another Windows 10 machine) can ping PC1 using the local IP address (10.1.1.2) but unable to ping using the hostname (e.g., mydesktop).

I can update client's Windows host file with the hostname,
but if there are many clients this would not be very feasible.

I tried adding `push "dhcp-option DOMAIN local"` to
sever.ovpn 
but it didn't help. I also tried adding a static DNS record to the router, but when client `PING mydesktop`, it gives this error: `Ping request could not find host mydesktop. Please check the name and try again.`

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant, but for Windows clients you can use `block-outside-dns` in the client conf to prevent DNS leak.

Comment: Since you are relying on DNS for this, have you made sure that the server can actually resolve it anyway? (With dig / nslookup /...)

Comment: @TomYan `nslookup mydesktop` get resolved in both server and client. But `ping mydesktop` returns the mentioned error message for the client.

Comment: Just try `block-outside-dns` on the clients then. I actually had similar problem: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/910

Comment: @TomYan Unfortunately `block-outside-dns` did not help me with my case. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `dev tap` instead. 
It was the solution for me. 
I assume it is not possible with `dev tun`.